# asp net core read appsetting special character

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

I need to read a value in the controller from the appsettings.json file and send it to the view. The value contains some special character, like letter with accent mark, for example "atención".

The problem is that the special character is not shown properly.

In the startup class I do that:

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<ApplicationSettings(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
```

Where **ApplicationSettings** is a class for hold the configuration values.

And then in the controller:

```
private IOptions<ApplicationSettings> _settings;
public StudentController(IOptions<ApplicationSettings> settings)
{
    _settings = settings;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var testSetting = _settings.Value.TestSetting;
    return new ObjectResult(testSetting);
}
```

testStting value has stranger's character instead of accent marks.

Any idea?

Thanks, regards!

Comment: Is the file encoded properly (using UTF-8)? Is the output encoded properly? Is the browser determining the correct encoding for your output? What does the value look like when debugging?

Comment: Could you share us a project to reproduce your issue? I made a test with [OptionsController](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/OptionsPro/Controllers/OptionsController.cs#L27), but it works correctly. What is your current result?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, I solved the issue changing encoding of appsettings json to UTF-8. Regards!!

Comment: I have a solution using xml. Please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56661446/4703859