# appsettings with special characters in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a small .NET Core console app which has an `appsettings.json` file containing different configuration sections and some of the values contain accents (for example `á` or `ó`).

When I parse a given configuration section I get weird chars back for those.

Is there an option in the configuration namespace that could help in parsing the string correctly?

Real example:

```
{
  "Loc": "https://www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg",
  "Caption": "Ocasión - Los mejores vehículos"
},
```

Comment: There are no special characters. If the file is saved as UTF8, .NET will read it just fine. The proof is this very question - StackOverflow is an ASP.NET site and the pages are encoded using UTF8

Comment: If you get weird characters it means the file was saved using a single-byte codepage instead of UTF8. Save it again as UTF8. .NET's `File` methods use UTF8 as the default file encoding

Comment: @habib not related. This isn't a question about backslashes

Answer (score 70, accepted):

JSON mandates UTF-8 as the file encoding. Your file is most likely saved in some other encoding, possibly Codepage 1252. Make sure you save the file as UTF-8 and your characters will work.

Different tools handle this differently.

For Notepad there's an *Encoding* selection in the Save dialog:

[image]

Visual Studio has a *Save with Encoding* option in the Save dialog:

[image]

You could also write a small program or script to do the conversion, e.g. the following PowerShell pipeline:

```
(Get-Content appsettings.json) | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 appsettings.json
```

Comment: In my case I just converted my file with the PS command provided above.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [Deep Dive into Microsoft Configuration](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2018/06/20/microsoft-extensions-configuration-deep-dive/), I found a solution. My solution is to combine the use of json and xml.

In Your Program.cs, You need to add the load of xml. Example where I map settings to a POCO:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(AddDbConfiguration)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

    private static void AddDbConfiguration(WebHostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var configuration = builder.Build();
        builder.AddXmlFile("appsettings.xml");
    }
```

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <ConfigSettings>
    <Database>Specialskolekørsel</Database>
    <SystemId>1</SystemId>
    <EnableAudit>True</EnableAudit>
    </ConfigSettings>
</root>
```

My ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   services.Configure<ConfigSettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ConfigSettings)));
}
```

My Controller:

```
public HomeController(IOptions<ConfigSettings> config)
{
    Database = config.Value.Database;
}
```

Now the danish letter ø shows as expected. I hope You will find this useful.

Comment: I guess this works because you set encoding in the file as utf-8. Does Json support this. As a funny sidenote, I am experiencing the same mess in .netcore 3.1 api of mine with the norwegian vocal ø. Same letter in our two languages. So I need to be careful with encoding of my json files, setting them to utf-8